# Create multiple variables based on character vector and apply function

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data.frame `df` that contains some job offer requirements. I have also a vector of particular skills `skills`. For each element of a character vector `skills` I want to create a binary variable with `TRUE` if requirements contain a particular skill and `FALSE` otherwise.

```r
df = structure(list(id = c(582L, 582L, 582L, 582L, 582L), requirements = c("rpg; as400; sql; db2; java; aws", 
"python; sql; r; linux; sas; aws", "oracle; microsoft sql server; mysql", 
"uml; bmpn; sql", ".net; c#; python; mvvm; java")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

#    id                        requirements
# 1 582     rpg; as400; sql; db2; java; aws
# 2 582     python; sql; r; linux; sas; aws
# 3 582 oracle; microsoft sql server; mysql
# 4 582                      uml; bmpn; sql
# 5 582        .net; c#; python; mvvm; java

skills = c("sql", "python", "aws", "java", "oracle")
```

Desired output:

```
#    id                        requirements   sql python   aws  java oracle
# 1 582     rpg; as400; sql; db2; java; aws  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
# 2 582     python; sql; r; linux; sas; aws  TRUE   TRUE  TRUE FALSE  FALSE
# 3 582 oracle; microsoft sql server; mysql  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE   TRUE
# 4 582                      uml; bmpn; sql  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE
# 5 582        .net; c#; python; mvvm; java FALSE   TRUE FALSE  TRUE  FALSE
```

I am looking for an elegant **tidy** approach using `mutate` and `across`. As I might know, it is possible to apply `across` only for existing columns, so firstly I created some using character vector `skills`, and then I applied `ifelse()` with `grepl` under `across` method, but it doesn't work for some reason.

```
df_processed = df %>% 
  `[<-`(., skills, value = NA) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(.cols = all_of(skills), ~ ifelse(grepl(colnames(.x), requirements), T, F))
  )
```

Here I try to apply colnames of selected columns (`skills`) as an argument of `grepl` function, but it doesn't work. Since code below works, I guess that `colnames(.x)` doesn't work properly:

```
across(.cols = all_of(skills), ~ 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

###### Method 1

Create new columns with elements of `skills` as column names, and apply `grepl()` across these columns.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  `[<-`(skills, value = NA) %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(skills), ~ grepl(cur_column(), requirements)))
```

---

###### Method 2

Use `sapply()` in `mutate()`.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(as.data.frame(sapply(skills, \(x) grepl(x, requirements))))
```

---

###### Method 3

A feasible but some complex way is splitting `requirements` into rows and then spread to wider.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(rowid = row_number(), req = requirements) %>%
  separate_longer_delim(req, '; ') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = req, values_from = req,
              values_fn = ~ !is.na(.x), values_fill = FALSE) %>%
  select(id, requirements, all_of(skills))
```

---

###### Output

```
# # A tibble: 5 × 7
#      id requirements                        sql   python aws   java  oracle
#   <int> <chr>                               <lgl> <lgl>  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> 
# 1   582 rpg; as400; sql; db2; java; aws     TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE 
# 2   582 python; sql; r; linux; sas; aws     TRUE  TRUE   TRUE  FALSE FALSE 
# 3   582 oracle; microsoft sql server; mysql FALSE FALSE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  
# 4   582 uml; bmpn; sql                      TRUE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE 
# 5   582 .net; c#; python; mvvm; java        FALSE TRUE   FALSE TRUE  FALSE
```

Comment: thank you @Darren, could you please explain the `[<-`  what it the name of this function and how it works

Comment: @jkatam In R, any binary operators, e.g. `a + b`, could be written as `\`+\`(a, b)`, and you can move the first argument outside the pipeline: `a %>% \`+\`(b)`. So `df %>% \`[<-\`(skills, value = NA)` is actually equivalent to `df[skills] <-  NA`.

Answer (score 2):

I find @Darren Tsai options intriguing.

The following is an alternative based on `{dplyr}`& `{purrr}`.
It avoids creating dummy NA columns as `across()` only works on columns that already exist.

```
# create a vector of the skills you are looking for (and to make grepl() 
# i.e. use your skills vector

# then "loop"/iterate over `what_you_look_for` = `skills` and bind the results into columns

skills |> 
  map_dfc(.f = ~ grepl(pattern = .x, x = df$requirements)) |> 
  # set names of the columns you created
  set_names(skills) |> 
  # ----------- in case output shall look like you wanted it
  # bind original data frame and reorder columns
  bind_cols(df) |> 
  select(id, requirements, everything())
```

This yields:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 7
     id requirements                        sql   python aws   java  oracle
  <int> <chr>                               <lgl> <lgl>  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> 
1   582 rpg; as400; sql; db2; java; aws     TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE 
2   582 python; sql; r; linux; sas; aws     TRUE  TRUE   TRUE  FALSE FALSE 
3   582 oracle; microsoft sql server; mysql TRUE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  
4   582 uml; bmpn; sql                      TRUE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE 
5   582 .net; c#; python; mvvm; java        FALSE TRUE   FALSE TRUE  FALSE
```

There is a message for the newly created columns. I am not sure how to suppress this other than `suppressMessages(...)`. So maybe someone can add this to the pipe-chain.

Comment: thank your, also tried to use"map_dfc"

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively please try the `list` approach

```r
lists <- map(skills, \(x) {
  y <- df %>% mutate(!!sym(x) := str_detect(requirements,x)) %>% pull(!! sym(x))
  assign(x,y,envir = .GlobalEnv)
})

cbind(df,setNames(lists, skills) %>% as.data.frame())
```

````
   id                        requirements   sql python   aws  java
1 582     rpg; as400; sql; db2; java; aws  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
2 582     python; sql; r; linux; sas; aws  TRUE   TRUE  TRUE FALSE
3 582 oracle; microsoft sql server; mysql  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
4 582                      uml; bmpn; sql  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
5 582        .net; c#; python; mvvm; java FALSE   TRUE FALSE  TRUE
  oracle
1  FALSE
2  FALSE
3   TRUE
4  FALSE
5  FALSE
```
````

Comment: it looks complicated, especially bangbang operators